# Calculate distance base on value that is vary

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]
I am new to Mathematica.
I am stuck at getting one specific value after calculating with value that is changing from 0.5 to 1.0

I have value 400 and from that I want to go to destination 720 using vary value.

like:

720-400 = 320 (with changing value).

now this 320 value is divide in 0.5 to 1.0 in that way that the final value become 320
for example

I want value in series in that way that in changing value is 0.5 than my value is 400 and after iterate from 0.51,0.52,0.53... upto 1.0 . result become 720.

How can I calculate this to match the result

**for example :::**

my starting value is 400 (vary value is 0.50) . 
now I want to reach at number 720 (vary value will be 1.00)
and I also have one value that is changing in my equation (0.51,0.52,0.53 upto 1.0)

now 0.51 upto 1.0 value to be calculate in such a way that after calculation last value must be 720

mean when 0.50 the related value is 400 then after iteration reach to 1.0 it has to become 720.

so what will be the formula?

Comment: please see my edited question @Mr.Wizard

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Its sounds like you want a linear interpolation in two dimensions, parametrized over the interval \[0.5, 1.0\].  First however is this question related to Wolfram *Mathematica* or shall I migrate it to [Math.SE]?

Comment: yes please @Mr.Wizard

Answer (score 1):

For a each dimension you can use this formula:

$$\frac{\text{a1} (x-q)+\text{a2} (p-x)}{p-q}$$

Where $a1$ and $a2$ are your target start and end values, $p$ and $q$ are the end points of the interval over which your parameter will vary, and $x$ is the parameter of the linear interpolation.

For example (in *Mathematica* code):

```
{a1, a2} = {300, 720};

{p, q} = {0.5, 1.0};

Plot[(a1 (x - q) + a2 (p - x))/(p - q), {x, 0.5, 1.0}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @Mr.Wizard  . it is working